# Getting a blank page in codeginter

Tags: codeigniter-3

I am getting a blank page instead of errors. and also my session variables are not working.

```
function login(){
  $uname=$this->input->post('uname');
  $upass=$this->input->post('upass');
  $login_status=$this->Loginmodel->logincheck($uname,$upass);
  if ($login_status) {
    $this->session->set_userdata('logintrue', '1122');
    $this->session->set_userdata('username', $uname); 
    redirect(base_url()."FT_admin/Home", '');
  } else
  {
      $data['title']="Ftre | Admin-Home"; 
      $data['Error']="Invalid detaisl"; 
      $this->load->view('admin/A_header',$data);
      $this->load->view('admin/A_login',$data); 
      $this->load->view('admin/A_footer',$data);
  }
}
```

Comment: pls help me.....

Comment: Check apache log for errors.

Comment: Please check apache error log and put error_reporting(1); an index.php file check which error do you face.